# Low validation accuracy with good training accuracy - keras imagedatagenerator flow_from_directory categorical classification

Tags: python, image, keras

I am trying to classify the Kaggle 10k dog images to 120 breeds using Keras and ResNet50. Due to memory constraints at Kaggle (14gb ram) - I have to use the ImageDataGenerator that feeds the images to the model and also allows data augmentation - in real time.

The base convoluted ResNet50 model:

```
conv_base = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224,224, 3))
```

My model:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(120, activation='softmax'))
```

Making sure that only my last added layers are trainable - so the ResNet50 original weights will not be modified in the training process and compiling model:

```
conv_base.trainable = False
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(), loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

Num trainable weights BEFORE freezing the conv base: 216
Num trainable weights AFTER freezing the conv base: 4
```

And the final model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
resnet50 (Model)             (None, 1, 1, 2048)        23587712  
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 2048)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               524544    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 120)               30840     
=================================================================
Total params: 24,143,096
Trainable params: 555,384
Non-trainable params: 23,587,712
_________________________________________________________________
```

The train and validation directories have each, 120 sub directories - one for each dog breed. In these folders are images of dogs. Keras is supposed to use these directories to get the correct label for each image: so an image from a "beagle" sub dir is classified automatically by Keras - no need for one-hot-encoding or anything like that.

```
train_dir = '../input/dogs-separated/train_dir/train_dir/'
validation_dir = '../input/dogs-separated/validation_dir/validation_dir/'

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
train_dir,target_size=(224, 224),batch_size=20, shuffle=True)
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
validation_dir,target_size=(224, 224),batch_size=20, shuffle=True)

Found 8185 images belonging to 120 classes.
Found 2037 images belonging to 120 classes.
```

Just to make sure these classes are right and in the right order I've compared their train_generator.class_indices and validation_generator.class_indices - and they are the same.
Train the model:

```
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
steps_per_epoch=8185 // 20,epochs=10,
validation_data=validation_generator,
validation_steps=2037 // 20)
```

Note in the charts below, that while training accuracy improves as expected - the validation sets quickly around 0.008 which is 1/120...RANDOM prediction ?!

[image]

[image]

I've also replaced the train with validation and vice versa - and got the same issue: training accuracy improving while the validation accuracy got stuck on approx 0.008 = 1/120.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect the default learning rate (`1e-3`) is high. Have you tried a lower learning rate like `1e-4` or `2e-5` or `1e-5`? You can set the learning rate by: `optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate)`.

Comment: Tried lr=1e-5. Doesn't help with the validation accuracy, which gets stuck on 0.0074 - while the training accuracy improves slowly. It seems that during validation, it completely disregards the directory structure of the 120 breeds and is predicting randomly...

Comment: I've updated the charts above to reflect the learning rate 
   model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-5),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

Comment: What version of Keras are you using, i.e. `print(keras.__version__)`?

Comment: Keras version 2.1.5...the one provided by Kaggle kernels...

Comment: Strange indeed! There seems to be nothing wrong with your codes. If you can, try to reproduce the issue on another machine or if Kaggle allows it, upgrade the Keras/Tensorflow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179919/discussion-between-toren-and-today).

Comment: Any updates/progress?

Comment: posted question on google keras group

Comment: Same problem here with transfer learning using any pre-trained model and flow_from_dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I've played with the **batch size** and found batch_size = 120 (the number of directories in the train as well as the valid directories) to eliminate the above issue. Now I can happily employ data augmentation techniques without crashing my Kaggle kernel on memory issues. Still I wonder...

*How is Keras ImageDataGenerator sampling images from a directory when in categorical classification mode - depth or breadth wise ?*

If depth wise - than with a batch size of 20 it will go thru the FIRST directory of say 100 photos (five times), and then move to the next directory, do it in batches of 20, move to the next dir...
Or is it breadthwise ?

Breadthwise - the initial batch of 20 will be ONE photo from each of the first 20 directories and then the next 20 directories ?
I couldn't find in the documentation how is Keras ImageDataGenerator working with batches when used with **flow_from _directory** and fit_generator.

Comment: Keras was updated at Kaggle to 2.2.2 - so this fact may have helped solve the issue