# Keras ImageDataGenerator Low Validation Accuracy

Tags: keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to preform transfer learning with mobilenetv2 to classify 196 classes of cars from the cars-196 dataset of stanford.

My work environment is google colab notebook.
I use the ImageDataGenerator from keras to load the images for the train and validation.
On the training images I also perform data augmentation.

The following code is how I perform it:

```py
# To load the dataset from the drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import math
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dropout, ReLU, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import MobileNetV2, preprocess_input

BATCH_SIZE = 196

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=20,  # Rotate the augmented image by 20 degrees
    zoom_range=0.2,  # Zoom by 20% more or less
    horizontal_flip=True,  # Allow for horizontal flips of augmented images
    brightness_range=[0.8, 1.2],  # Lighter and darker images by 20%
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    preprocessing_function=preprocess_input
)


img_data_iterator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    # Where to take the data from, the classes are the sub folder names
    '/content/drive/My Drive/Datasets/cars-196/car_data/train',
    class_mode="categorical",  # classes are in 2D one hot encoded way, default is true but just to point it out
    shuffle=True,  # shuffle the data, default is true but just to point it out
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    target_size=(224, 224)  # This size is the default of mobilenet NN
)

validation_img_data_iterator = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(
    '/content/drive/My Drive/Datasets/cars-196/car_data/test',
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=True,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    target_size=(224, 224)
)

base_model = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
preds = Dense(196, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=preds)

# Disable training of already trained layer
for layer in model.layers[:-3]:
    layer.trainable = False

model.compile(optimizer='Adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

# define the checkpoint
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
filepath = "/content/drive/My Drive/Datasets/cars-196/model.h5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

history = model.fit(
    img_data_iterator,
    steps_per_epoch=math.ceil(8144/BATCH_SIZE),  # 8144 is the number of training images
    validation_steps=math.ceil(8062/BATCH_SIZE),  # 8062 is the number of validation images
    validation_data=validation_img_data_iterator,
    epochs=100,
    callbacks=callbacks_list
)
```

About the batch size, from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52251199/low-validation-accuracy-with-good-training-accuracy-keras-imagedatagenerator-f) I decided to set the batch size as the number of labels available, but it did not change anything in terms of `val_accuracy`.

I've added a dropout of 0.5 between the fully connected layers that I have added, but again, no change in the accuracy of the validation.

My accuracy on the training set arrives to about 92% while the validation accuracy stays at about 0.7%.

My guess is that the ImageDataGenerator is acting weird and screwing up the accuracy, but I have not found any solution for the problem so ATM I dont have a clew what is the reason behind it.

Does anyone have any guesses as to what might be the problem?

----- EDIT

The train and test folder all have sub folders with name of the labels (the different cars I want to identify) and each subfolder has images of that car. This is just how the cars-196 dataset is. The ImageDataGenerator attaches the right label to the image, depending on in what subfolder that image was in.

Comment: Is your test and train data properly shuffled?

Comment: In the function `flow_from_directory` I set the `shuffle` parameter to True (it is True by default but I just do it anyway), so I guess it is shuffled, although maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: You have 2 different folders for your train and test data. The `img_data_iterator` is only getting data from the the `train` dir, while the `validation_img_data_iterator` is getting the data from `test` dir

Comment: But I have added the `shuffle=True` to both of them, am I missing something?

Comment: Lets take an example, You are trying to check if your images have dogs, cats, tigers, deers, lions. So you have 5 classes. You have gone and collected images uniformly and divided them into train and test folders. But you didn't shuffle when you divided the data into train and test folder, as a result it seems that you train folder almost doesn't have any image of lion while your test folder has all the lion images. In this case your trained model will not work well on your validation set.

Comment: Ok so maybe I had to mention it, the train and test folder all have sub folders of the labels (the different cars I want to identify) and each subfolder has images of that car. This is just how the cars-196 dataset is. The ImageDataGenerator attaches the right label to the image, depending on in what subfolder that image was in.

Comment: Yeah I am just ruling out shuffling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222618/discussion-between-max-and-mb0850).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I did not apply the `preprocess_input` function to the validation data image generator.

Instead of

```py
validation_img_data_iterator = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(
    '/content/drive/My Drive/Datasets/cars-196/car_data/test',
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=True,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    target_size=(224, 224)
)
```

Changed it to

```py
validation_img_data_iterator = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=preprocess_input
).flow_from_directory(
    '/content/drive/My Drive/Datasets/cars-196/car_data/test',
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=True,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    target_size=(224, 224)
)
```